# Compiler error when using "near" as a variable name

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get a very weird error in my code. I created this class in C++:

```
class Tester{
    float f;
    Tester(float,float);
};
```

and i implemented it like this:

```
Tester::Tester(float near,float a){
    this->f=near/a;
}
```

i get the following error:

```
..\src\Tester.cpp: In constructor 'Tester::Tester(float, float)':
..\src\Tester.cpp:4:14: error: expected primary-expression before '/' token
  this->f=near/a;
              ^
```

when i rename `near` to something else the error disappears. thats not a big deal of course because i can rename the variable, but i was just curious if someone of you knows the reason.

**Update:**

The reason is the inlusion of `windef.h`. it was included by `windows.h` via `wglext.h`.

Comment: maybe try #undef near?

Comment: You may want to mention the platform and toolchain you're using. It is likely going to matter.

Comment: maybe try also making constructor public. for me [it works](http://ideone.com/IHzBDX)

Comment: These are hangovers from the bad old days of near and far memory addressing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869830/near-and-far-pointers

Comment: thanks, i just found it, #undef worked fine too. i didnt know about the memory keywords.

Comment: What compiler and version of that compiler are you using?

Comment: as far as i know gcc 4.8.1. 
and i think i found the culprit: it was `windows.h`
wglext.h included it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that near is defined as a macro by the compiler in some header. Usually this macro is used with "near" pointers.