# Can't name variables "far" and "near" when using GLAD

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I generated a loader with http://glad.dav1d.de/

- Language: C/C++
- GL: Version 4.5
- Profile: Core

When I include `glad.h` in any file, variable names of `near` and `far` can't be used. It results in an `expected an identifier`, and `Error C2513 no variable declared before '='` on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

```
#include <glad\glad.h>

int main()
{
    float near = 1.0f;
    char far = 2.0f;

    return 0;
}
```

The only place where I could find `near` and `far` in `glad.h`

```
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLDEPTHRANGEPROC)(GLdouble near, GLdouble far);
GLAPI PFNGLDEPTHRANGEPROC glad_glDepthRange;
```

Comment: I guess that those identifiers are used somewhere in your `glad.h` file...

Comment: @Rames In a function pointer declaration...

Comment: It seems VC++ have some backward compatibility to old DOS code where compilers used to have such keywords as extensions. It's probably macros that expands to nothing these days though (which means the declarations look like e.g. `float = 1.0f;`)

Comment: It was working for the past 3 weeks until I switched to GLAD today from GLEW

Comment: Then maybe the GLAD headers include some system header that defines those macros, some header that GLEW didn't include?

Comment: By the way, you can easily check what the preprocessor generates, there are flags to only preprocess the source, then open the preprocessed file and see what the compiler sees.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right. I found it. It's in `windef.h`. There's macros for `near`, `far`, `pascal`, `FAR`, and `NEAR`... All of them causes the same errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these names are defined as macros in the header or in a header that is included by this header

Usually these names are used for defining so-called near and far addresses.

Comment: Why post an almost duplicate answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/22848865/4342498?

Comment: @NathanOliver Because Vlad is eager about getting the rep points as always  ;-P ...

Comment: There's a cure for that ;)