# How to convert int to LPBYTE

Tags: c++, casting

I need to convert int value to LPBYTE. when I look at the definitions is shows like this. I'm not sure what is `far` word says.

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
typedef BYTE far            *LPBYTE;
```

1. What is the meaning of 'far'
2. How to convert int value to LPBYTE

**Edit**

```
foo(LPBYTE x){
}

int main()
{
 int y = koo();
 foo(y); // how to cast here
 return 0;
}
```

**Actual code**

```
 int iVal = 0;
 LONG res = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"UseSystemSeparators", NULL, &lpType, (LPBYTE)iVal, &size);
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869830/near-and-far-pointers) is an explanation

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: int to a pointer

Comment: Can you please clarify your question, is it about the `far` keyword? Or is it about "converting" to a pointer? If the latter, do you want to convert the `int` to a pointer, or do you want to get a pointer to the `int`?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have an `int` variable that contains an *address*? Or do you want to get the address of the `int` variable?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: edit the question, than for the comments

Comment: The *far* keyword dates back to the 16-bit version of Windows, it declared the pointer to be a 32-bit pointer.  Not relevant anymore today.  When you want to cast *int* to LPBYTE then you haven't written enough 64-bit code, time to get cracking at it.

Comment: Agree with Hans. You might have chosen a type which is too small. `INT_PTR`  is a Windows type that's int-like but large enough to hold a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the *address of the variable*, and then convert that address to `LPBYTE`.

Then you need to use the address-of operator `&` on the variable to get a pointer to the variable, and cast that pointer:

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&y));
```

---

<strike>If the variable actually hold an address, then you first of all have to be very careful because it's not guaranteed that `int` can hold a memory address (i.e. a pointer). Think for example on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits, but `int` is usually still a 32 bit type.</strike>

Use instead `intptr_t` which is guaranteed to be big enough to hold either an `int` or a pointer.

Then you should do e.g.

```
intptr_t y = ...;

foo(reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(y));
```

Comment: No I need to convert the value of the int variable to LPBYTE. because Int hold a resource handler

Comment: shows a warning with reinterpret_cast `warning C4312: 'reinterpret_cast': conversion from 'int' to 'LPBYTE' of greater size`

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya You get the warning because `int` is smaller than a pointer. You should look at the code where you assign the variable, are you *really* assigning an address and storing it in the variable? You should update the question to show some *actual* code instead.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya The second-to-last argument is a pointer to the variable that receives the data, so it's the *first* part of my answer that you should read! Otherwise, since it's zero, it's equal to passing a `NULL` pointer, which [according to the official reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is telling the function to not read the data.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Also you should be careful, do you *know* that the data stored in the registry key is equal or smaller than the size of an `int`? Otherwise you might write beyond the limits of it and end up with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what is far word says.

`far` is a 32-bit pointer which consists of 16-bit 'selector' that helps in determining the start address of the memory region, and a 16-bit offset into the memory region.

You can cast your variable like this:

```
int main()
{
 int y = koo();
 foo(static_cast<LPBYTE>(&y)); 
 return 0;
}
```